# How to hide urls of hyperlink in outlook?

Tags: css, html, email

I am sending mail through my emailer and in my email i am sending an image with the background hyperlink, the email showing normal but in system configured outlook showing the link of URL  of the hyperlink.

Please visit below mention URL
https://prnt.sc/itb5wq

I am trying to hide URL using placing span or p tag before hyperlink.

**Source code:**

```
<span style="color:#ffffff;">Text Something</span>

<a href="#" id="m-banner-anchor">
```

Comment: Nothing sketchy about this, I'm sure.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code and worked for me perfectly:

```
<span style="opacity:0"><font color="white" size="1">Text Here</font></span><br><br>
<a href="#" id="m-banner-anchor">
<img src="images/cengage_promo_header.jpg" id="m-banner-image" height="184" width="755" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach was not that bad, here's the correct syntax for a HTML hyperlink:

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com">I am a link and you can't see my destination!</a>
```

Or in your case:

```html
<a href="#" id="m-banner-anchor"><span style="color: #fffff">Text Something</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your span in your hyperlink ...

```
<a href="#" id="m-banner-anchor"> <span style="color:#ffffff;">Please Visit</span> </a>
```